# One grid warps more than the other, how to change this?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I have a problem at the moment and don't know how to change this. i use a grid. and this works before. but now the grid pulls down with it which i don't want. How can i change this? I use Tailwind

`<section class="grid md:grid-cols-4 grid-flow-row-dense gap-4 p-4">`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
align-items: start;
```

which, using bootstrap (as it appears you are) would be class `align-items-md-start` (where `md` is the usual responsive cutoff).